# Max If array formula with multiple criteria (no pivot tables)

Tags: arrays, excel-formula

I'm trying to return the MAX date `[G-Step Complete]` 
 
for a series of rows with same values `[CONCAT]`, 
IF the date column `[G-Step Complete]` does **NOT** contain a BLANK.
 However, if the date column `[G-Step Complete]` **does** contain a BLANK, return 0.

This is the array formula I am working with:

```
=MAX(IF([CONCAT]=[@CONCAT],IF(ISBLANK([G-Step Complete]),0,[G-Step Complete])))
```

The `[CONCAT]` column is sorted such that like items are grouped together.

My expectation is that IF **any** rows for a given group of CONCAT values is blank, then I would expect a result of 0. If NO rows contain a BLANK, then I would expect the value to return the MAX date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `TB` being the name of the table, this should do in Excel 2007 (and above) syntax:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(([CONCAT]=TB[[#This Row],[CONCAT]])*ISBLANK([G-Step Complete])),0,
   LARGE([G-Step Complete]*(([CONCAT] = TB[[#This Row],[CONCAT]])), 1))
```

could be shortened with the `@` operator in Excel 2010 and above versions:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(([CONCAT]=[@CONCAT])*ISBLANK([G-Step Complete])),0,
   LARGE([G-Step Complete]*(([CONCAT]=[@CONCAT])), 1))
```